# Create array of all values of a certain field of a nested array within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to take all of the thumbnailURL's in my data set and add them to an array.

I have tried a .map and a .push and have thought about having to change things up because it is an object, I'll show you the data set and I'll show you my methods:

So just to be clear, I want to check each roles array and take from each account the thumbnail URL and add it to an array:

In my code snippet, it works and it is identical to my actual code, the data and the logic, but in my real code I get the error:

```
this.participantImage.push is not a function
```

data:

```
session =   {
"id": "34343434343",
"endDatetime": "2017-01-19T18:00:00.000+0000",
"location": "frfefef-4354, Congress Centre, Sanddadadaada",
"name": "jeffs's Next Frontier",
"photoURL": "25345345345",
"roles": [{
        "account": {
            "id": "24234324",
            "fullName": "darren Lacy",
            "thumbnailURL": "thumbnail image 1232343433"
        }
    },
    {
        "account": {
            "id": "0056565",
            "fullName": "jeff Lacy",
            "thumbnailURL": "thumbnail image 000000000"
        }

    }
]
}
```

working version:

```js
    session =   {
 "id": "34343434343",
 "endDatetime": "2017-01-19T18:00:00.000+0000",
 "location": "frfefef-4354, Congress Centre, Sanddadadaada",
 "name": "jeffs's Next Frontier",
 "photoURL": "25345345345",
 "roles": [{
   "account": {
    "id": "24234324",
    "fullName": "darren Lacy",
    "thumbnailURL": "thumbnail image 1232343433"
   }
  },
  {
   "account": {
    "id": "0056565",
    "fullName": "jeff Lacy",
    "thumbnailURL": "thumbnail image 000000000"
   }

  }
 ]
    }
    
    
    participantImage = []
    
    for (var i = 0; i < session.roles.length; i++) {
      participantImage.push(session.roles[i].account.thumbnailURL)
    }
    console.log(participantImage)
```

I use this function in my code:

```
 participantImage = [];

  getParticipantDetails(session) {
console.log('CONSOLING SESSION AGAIN!!!!!!!!!' + JSON.stringify(session))
    for (var i = 0; i < session.roles.length; i++) {
      this.participantImage.push(session.roles[i].account.thumbnailURL)
    }
    return this.participantImage;
  }
```

which is identical data, has anyone an idea of why it doesnt work?

I need the array of the thumbnail images as I am parsing them through to a component where they can be iterated over:

my component:

```
        <session-card>
          [participantImages]="getParticipantDetails(session)"
        </session-card>
```

which parses through to my parent component

```
  @Input() participantImages?: any[] = [];


  <div class="Session-Participants">
  <div  *ngFor="let image of participantImages" >
      <img [src]='image' width=100px/>
  </div>
```

Thanks so much if you can help?

Comment: why you are pushing again when you already have the thumbnails?

Comment: I need them in an array as I am parsing them through to a component I am using angular, they are images, i send them as an array and then I use an ngFor on the array to display the images.

Comment: The only difference which I see is you have `this.participantImage` instead of `participantImage`. Maybe `this` is the reason.

Comment: you already have array you do not need function as far as I know, please explain more

Comment: show us where you declare this.participantImage: It is not being declared as an array. Are you binding 'this' to getParticipantDetails?

Comment: I'm going to post more of the code

Comment: @jalynn2 I have just updated the code, I parse through the array to my parent component where I am trying to iterate through it to display the images, now do you understand why I need the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const thumbnails = session.roles.map(role => role.account.thumbnailURL);`

`// ["thumbnail image 1232343433", "thumbnail image 000000000"]`

Comment: Hah, that's actually way simpler than my answer. @Sparlarva you should accept this one.

Comment: Xceno's answer is exactly the same as mine and the original response was updated to be what i said to do.

Comment: I used the original solution.

Comment: Whilst they more or less do the same thing. `.map` is the method to use for your purpose if you want to take the best approach.

Comment: Oh okay yes I've just tried it and it worked, sorry I was premature with my response, I will update the correct answer, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: So, to make this answer a bit more useful:

- If you can, look out for function calls in your HTML templates.
  Just put a breakpoint in there and look how often they're actually called, depending on what your functions do, it can have a tremendous impact on performance.
- My initial answer mentioned `reduce()`, which was completely overkill. If you just want to extract some data from an array, `map()` is mostly all you need.
- This one is highly subjective: Your code suggests that `participantImage` is a public field on your component, that gets mutated by the `getParticipantDetails` call, so there's little point in returning it. Actually, the whole function can be replaced by a call to `map()`.
- **Why your initial function didn't work (probably)**:
  Since you're not using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you have to be careful with your `this`. In your example, you probably passed the function around, which changed the scope of your `this`. So `participantImages` didn't exist in that scope, hence the exception.

**ORIGINAL:**
Not a direct answer to your problem, but you could save yourself some headaches with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const session = {
  id: "34343434343",
  endDatetime: "2017-01-19T18:00:00.000+0000",
  location: "frfefef-4354, Congress Centre, Sanddadadaada",
  name: "jeffs's Next Frontier",
  photoURL: "25345345345",
  roles: [
    {
      account: {
        id: "24234324",
        fullName: "darren Lacy",
        thumbnailURL: "thumbnail image 1232343433"
      }
    },
    {
      account: {
        id: "0056565",
        fullName: "jeff Lacy",
        thumbnailURL: "thumbnail image 000000000"
      }
    }
  ]
};


const result = session.roles.map(x => x.account.thumbnailURL);
```

Comment: It worked! Im not sure why this worked, while the other push didn't?